# symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 cpp/mm files

Tags: c++, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, compiler-errors

I'm working with Cocos2D and I created a Singleton C++ class that will store Game Settings information.  This is what my class looks like:

```
#include <cstddef>
#ifndef __pyramidofdoom__GameSettings__
#define __pyramidofdoom__GameSettings__


#endif /* defined(__pyramidofdoom__GameSettings__) */

 class GameSettings {
 private:
  static GameSettings* mGameSettings;
  GameSettings(){ mGameSettings = this; }
  int rowSelected = 0;


public:

GameSettings *getInstance() {

    if (mGameSettings == NULL)
        mGameSettings = new GameSettings();
        return mGameSettings;

};

int getSelectedRow() { return rowSelected; }
void setSelectedRow(int row) { rowSelected = row;}
```

};

This is how I use it in cocos2D mm file:

```
        GameSettings *gameSettings = gameSettings->getInstance();

        if(multi)
            gameSettings->setSelectedRow(3);
        else
            gameSettings->setSelectedRow(1);
```

Seems basic enough to have everything working fine.

This is the error I'm getting when I try to build now:

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
 "GameSettings::mGameSettings", referenced from:
     GameSettings::getInstance() in GameLayer-E06C3150ABD8625A.o
    GameSettings::GameSettings() in GameLayer-E06C3150ABD8625A.o
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I made sure that the cpp/h file is included for Compile Sources under Build Phases.  I also added libc++ Library to see if that would fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any header or implementation where you `#import` and use a cpp class must also use the `.mm` extension.

So if you import the GameSettings.h and use the GameSettings cpp class in GameLayer.m you have to rename it GameLayer.mm.

You may want to prefer using an Objective-C class instead. Ideally scrap the whole singleton altogether. For example a reference in app delegate to a settings class instantiated on app launch works just as well.

Answer (score 1):

You've declared `mGameSettings`, but not defined it. You'll need a definition in a source file:

```
GameSettings* mGameSettings = NULL;
```

Alternatively, you could make it a local static variable:

```
GameSettings *getInstance() {
    static GameSettings instance;
    return instance;
}
```

which has the advantage of not leaking memory and being thread-safe (in a conforming C++11 compiler), if that's important to you.

Alternatively, get rid of the singleton. They're almost never a good idea ([What is so bad about singletons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975)), especially in C++ where you get a host of lifetime issues in addition to the excessive coupling and restricted testability inherent in the pattern.

Also, don't use reserved names for your include guards: [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783) More importantly, it should guard the entire header - yours does nothing.